# Running out of memory when executing composer inside a docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, composer-php

I'm running composer on docker container and I'm trying to install predis so I run the command

> docker-compose run --rm composer require predis/predis

But I get this error

[image]

Can someone explain me how to fix?

that's my dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm-alpine

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN composer --version
```

and that's my docker-compose

```
   services:
      nginx:
        image: nginx:stable-alpine
        container_name: nginx
        ports: 
          - "8088:80"
        volumes: 
          - ./src:/var/www/html 
          - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
        depends_on: 
        - mysql
        - php
        networks: 
        - laravel

      mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7.22
        container_name: mysql
        restart: unless-stopped
        tty: true
        ports: 
          - "4306:3306"
        environment: 
          MYSQL_DATABASE: homestead
          MYSQL_USER: homestead
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
          SERVICE_TAGS: dev
          SERVICE_NAME: mysql
        networks: 
        - laravel

      php:
        build: 
          context: .
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        container_name: php
        volumes: 
          - ./src:/var/www/html
        ports:
          - "9000:9000"
        networks: 
          - laravel

      redis:
            image: redis:5.0.0-alpine
            restart: always
            container_name: redis
            ports:
                - "6379:6379"
            networks:
              - laravel
```

Comment: Usually commands like `docker-compose run` will write out text to the console, not an image.  Can you replace that image with the actual output of the command?  Can you also include a [mcve] with enough source code (probably at least the relevant `docker-compose.yml` block and the image's `Dockerfile`) to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: @David edited it

Answer (score 0):

In your docker-compose file, add an environment entry with COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT: -1  to your php service

So your php services look like -

```
  php:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: php
    volumes: 
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    environment:
      COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT: -1
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks: 
      - laravel
```